# How to create and insert into a table with list fields in Flask-SQLAlchemy database model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple database model to represent a Team. Each team can have 4 team members, and for each member their name and T-Shirt size is to be stored.

```
from app import db

class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
    college_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    team_members = [db.Column(db.String(64), default="-") for _ in range(4)]
    tshirt_sizes = [db.Column(db.String(2), default="-") for _ in range(4)]
```

I am using Flask-Migrate, when the database is initialized the columns for team_members and tshirt_sizes are not created. How do I go about creating the table with the required number of columns, and also insert data into the table?

Django has [ListFields](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html), I am looking for something similar.

Comment: could you create two more tables for `TeamMember` and `TshirtSize` and then use relationships for the mappings? This seems to be what one would more commonly do.

Comment: This might help you: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html

Comment: Even if this somehow worked the way you've tried, it'd go against [1st normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), since team members and shirt sizes would form repeating groups. Do as @k-nut suggested. If you insist on denormalizing, then the solution is to create the columns as you normally would: `team_member_1 = db.Columb(...)` etc. Or if using Postgres or some other DB that supports arrays, with an array type column.

Comment: Also if you're adamant, but your DB has no array or JSON type, you could create a [`TypeDecorator` for storing JSON in a text type column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#marshal-json-strings).